# Generate random number in java

Tags: java, list, random

am using some simple code, which should get data from config

my config looks like:

```
name: test
locationA: -457.0,5.0,-186.0
locationB: -454.0,5.0,-186.0
prisonfile: ./plugins/JB/test.prison
prisons:
- -454.0,4.0,-176.0
- -460.0,4.0,-176.0
- -457.0,5.0,-186.0
police:
- -460.0,5.0,-186.0
- -454.0,5.0,-186.0
- -457.0,5.0,-176.0
open: true
```

my code looks like:

```
public void enter(Player player, String lines, String lines2) 
    {
        World world = player.getWorld();
        HashMap<String, Object> prison = plugin.prisons.getPrison(world.getName(), false);

        File configFile = new File(prison.get("config").toString());
        FileConfiguration config = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(configFile);
        String listName = "police";
        List<String> list = config.getStringList(listName);
        Integer ListSize = list.size();
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1=r.nextInt(ListSize-1);
        String[] parts = list.get(i1).split(",");
        player.teleport(new Location(world, Float.parseFloat(parts[0]), Float.parseFloat(parts[1]), Float.parseFloat(parts[2])));
```

Code works corretly and teleporting me on random positions, but it always just port on first 2 positions and never port me on 3th one, i try to print out how many coordinations found ListSize in config and its 3 so i totaly dont understand.

p.s. i need to generate randoms between 0 and MaxNumber of positions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the argument to the `nextInt` method in this line:

```
int i1=r.nextInt(ListSize-1);
```

The range of the random number returned is `0` (inclusive) through `n - 1`, `n` being the parameter.  Quoting from [the Javadocs for the `nextInt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value **(exclusive)**, drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

(emphasis mine)

There is no need to subtract `1` from the list size here.  Try

```
int i1 = r.nextInt(ListSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a good random and a good seed... so you could use one of

```
java.util.Random random = null; // Declare the random Instance.
random = new java.util.Random(
    System.currentTimeMillis());
// or
random = new java.util.Random(System.nanoTime());
// or
random = new java.util.Random(System.nanoTime()
    ^ System.currentTimeMillis());
// or
random = new java.security.SecureRandom(); // Because it makes "security" claims! :)

random.nextInt(MaxNumber + 1); // for the range 0-MaxNumber (inclusive).
```